# query event_member table by uid

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

When I run this simple query:

```
SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = MY_FRIEND_UID
```

in the test [query console](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query/), I always get back an empty result set.However, if I replace `MY_FRIEND_ID` with `me()`, I get back my list of events.

My app is set to allow `user_events` and `friends_events`, so here is my question:

Is it possible to query the event_member by uid, given the uid is one of my friends?
if yes, why this query is not working?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. I turned out that the access token that I was using did not had the new permissions (exactly the same user_events and friends_events) because it was obtained before adding those permission to the app.

You can try to use use [Facebook Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) to Debug the permission of your currently used token and to easily generate a new token and run the HQL with it. In my case it turned out immediately that the problem was in the token permission and with new token everything worked like a charm.